# connect button to app delegate

Tags: xcode, facebook

I am following this tutorial, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso, and I am at the part where you add the logout button (step 4). I have put in the code, but I can't figure out a way to trigger the logout function, because I've been putting all the code in the app delegate files instead of view controller files, since that's what the tutorial has been instructing me to do. The code includes the setup for a button, but I don't know how to translate that to the storyboard file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following this guide: http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-A-Beginners-Guide-to-Storyboard-Connection

You are going to want to hold "control" and drag from the button to the view controller.  Once you do that it should pop up a list of IBAction methods to choose from.  Click the appropriate one.

It should look somewhat like this: 
[image]

EDIT 1:

You cannot connect IBActions from the app delegate. Just put it in your ViewController file. If it needs to be in the app delegate, in the VC IBAction call this:

```
-(IBAction)yourAction {
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate performSelector:@selector(yourOtherMethod)];
}
```

Comment: I am trying to connect the button with code in the app delegate, not the view controller. Is there a similar way of achieving this?

Comment: "YourAppDelegate" isn't recognized by the compiler, and when I replace it with "AppDelegate" I get another error

Comment: Replace "YourAppDelegate" with whatever the name of your AppDelegate file is.  Also change "yourOtherMethod" to the name of the method in your AppDelegate file.

Comment: Oh ok. But after I change YourAppDelegate to the name of my app delegate (which is just AppDelegate) I get the error: Initializing 'AppDelegate *' with an expression of incompatible type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate>'

Comment: Is (MyAppDelegateClass*) supposed to be the name of my AppDelegate class?

Comment: Yes.  A rule of thumb:  If someone uses the word "My" or "Your" in a name, it probably should be changed to the name of your file.

Comment: Ah there we go. I can't test it because my program's turned to crap, but no errors from this so I assume it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem.  I recommend you start putting all IBOutlet and IBActions in ViewController classes.  But this should work for when you really need to access the AppDelegate